# Hibernate not using @Table when doing DDL validation on startup. Using Flyway and TestContainers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, flyway

I am having an issue with Hibernate.
I am creating tables via Flyway migrations.
A snippet is shown below of part of the initial migration script.
The script does run (I can see it in DEBUG mode).

Following the script running, Hibernate's validator seems to not be using the table name for the entity I have provided it via `javax.persistence`.

Here is the entity with some omissions for clarity:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "IngredientCategories")
public class IngredientCategory implements IEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 128)
    private String name;

    ...
}
```

```sql
CREATE TABLE `IngredientCategories` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Looking at the logs, the Flyway migrations are run and then **afterwards** I get the hibernate validation errors.

```
2020-10-24 11:22:11.952 DEBUG 91583 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully completed migration of schema `test` to version 1 - init
2020-10-24 11:22:11.961 DEBUG 91583 --- [           main] o.f.c.i.s.JdbcTableSchemaHistory         : Schema History table `test`.`flyway_schema_history` successfully updated to reflect changes
2020-10-24 11:22:11.970  INFO 91583 --- [           main] o.f.core.internal.command.DbMigrate      : Successfully applied 1 migration to schema `test` (execution time 00:00.107s)
2020-10-24 11:22:11.972 DEBUG 91583 --- [           main] org.flywaydb.core.Flyway                 : Memory usage: 82 of 354M
2020-10-24 11:22:12.088  INFO 91583 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-10-24 11:22:12.125  INFO 91583 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.20.Final
2020-10-24 11:22:12.237  INFO 91583 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-10-24 11:22:12.350  INFO 91583 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
2020-10-24 11:22:12.998  WARN 91583 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ingredient_categories]
2020-10-24 11:22:12.998  INFO 91583 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-10-24 11:22:13.420  INFO 91583 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-10-24 11:22:13.428  INFO 91583 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-10-24 11:22:13.434 ERROR 91583 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing table [ingredient_categories]
```

I can not decide if this is a hibernate issue, a Flyway issue or a testing issue.

It is just a test "booting" the app:

```java
@SpringBootTest
@Testcontainers
class DataApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I have had a look around and can see that many people had an issue before Spring 2x where the tables were validated BEFORE flyway would generate schema...but it seems that that has been "fixed" and the default is Flyway migrations are run before.

The line where I think the issue shows Hibernate was expecting a table name of
`Schema-validation: missing table [ingredient_categories]`
So it seems to be not using the javax.constaint.Table `@Table(name="IngredientCategories")` annotation when running the and building the context/beans.

The app properties are not overly exciting...I am using TestContainers:

```
#=========INTEGRATION TESTS========#

## Using TestContainers
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:mysql:8.0.22:///

# Validate Schema
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = validate

logging.level.org.flywaydb=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From official [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-configure-hibernate-naming-strategy)

> By default, Spring Boot configures the physical naming strategy with
> SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy. This implementation provides the same
> table structure as Hibernate 4: all dots are replaced by underscores
> and **camel casing is replaced by underscores** as well. By default, all
> table names are generated in lower case, but it is possible to
> override that flag if your schema requires it.
>
> For example, **a TelephoneNumber entity is mapped to the**
> **telephone_number table**.

So `IngredientCategories` became `ingredient_categories`. For database table name general convention to use snake-case. You can create table with name in snake case

```
CREATE TABLE `ingredient_categories`
```

Or if you prefer to use Hibernate 5’s default instead , set the following property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Then your table's name remains `IngredientCategories` as given in `@Table` annotation. Details about [Hibernate 5 Naming Strategy Configuration](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-naming-strategy)

Comment: Thank you.
I may switch back to doing snake_case.
I've always just used hibernate in the past and let it set names of tables and columns.
I will stick with the convention, but it is nice to know you can change that :).

Comment: Further to add, it may sound daft but if you use @Table(name="MyTableName") is the only real purpose of that is to link an entity if it has very different tablename say adding hibernate to a very legacy system?
Like the actual legacy table name is "factory_personel" but in code a choice has been made to have the table represented by "FactoryWorker"?

Comment: Actually, all depends on choice, you can implement your naming strategy also. See here for details explanation  https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/userguide/html_single/chapters/domain/naming.html

Comment: And Case conversion is an extra facility since CamelCase is a general convention in Java & snake_case for the database.